# Linux library code injection & calls to identically named functions in SOs

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, code-injection

I have built a linux shared object which I inject into a 3rd party program to intercept some dynamic function calls using LD_PRELOAD.

The 3rd party program uses a SO "libabc.so" located at some path. My injected SO uses another SO, also called "libabc.so" located at another path (essentially identical but slight code differences).

My problem is now, that calls to a function "def" which appear in both libabc.so are always resolved by the first. (Presumably because it is loaded first?!) How can I get them to be resolved with the second libabc.so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless something changed since I used to do this, you will need to [dlopen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) the library you want to pass calls on to and call the function manually, something like;

```
handle = dlopen("/path/to/libabc.so", RTLD_LAZY);
otherDef = dlsym(handle, "def");
orderDef(parameter);
```

There is a complete example how to do this very thing at [LinuxJournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795).

Comment: I can see from /proc/PID/maps that the library I want to call has already been loaded. Is there any way to avoid having to specify explicitly the path to the library? In principle I would only need to pivot the function resolution from one library to the next on the list, no?

Comment: Not to my knowledge if it's a requirement to call them the same name, but if you renamed the preloaded library to `libabc_shim.so`, you should be able to just dlopen `libabc.so` and get a handle to the already loaded library.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use *one* `libabc.so` version, you can always use `LD_PRELOAD` to load it along with your own shared object before anything else.

If you want to use multiple versions, you have a few alternatives:

- Use [`dlopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) in your shared object to load that library. Since you have created a function injection object you should be familiar with this procedure. This is the more generic and powerful way - you could even mix & match functions from different library versions.
- Use a different `DT_SONAME` for the library version your shared object links against. Unfortunately this requires (slightly) changing the build system of that library and recompiling.
- Link your shared object statically against the library in question. Not always possible but it does not require modifying the library in question. The main issue with this alternative is that any change in the library should be followed by a relinking of your shared object for the changes to be pulled in.

  Warning: you may need to use a custom linker script or specific linker options to avoid symbol conflicts.